# '>' Terminal mode activated when I accidentally type an extra apostrophe

Tags: terminal

What is this mode please may someone enlighten me? Merci

I looked on the interwebs and couldn't find diddly squat at what mode it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless they're escaped, quotes (`'`) are used to surround a string and prevent the shell from parsing it. When you have a linebreak after an opening quote, you're telling the shell that you want to input a multilined string. The `>` is the continuation of the that string on another line.

Let's see an example that illustrates this:

```
mureinik@computer /tmp
$ echo 'this is the first line
> and this is the second
> and now we will terminate the string on the third, with a closing quote -> '
this is the first line
and this is the second
and now we will terminate the string on the third, with a closing quote ->
```